# kotlin getting a subscriber to observe an observable using RxJava2

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

```
Android Studio 3.0 Beta2
```

I have created 2 methods one that creates the observable and another that creates the subscriber.

However, I am having a issue try to get the subscriber to subscribe to the observable. In Java this would work, and I am trying to get it to work in Kotlin.

In my onCreate(..) method I am trying to set this. Is this the correct way to do this?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        /* CANNOT SET SUBSCRIBER TO SUBCRIBE TO THE OBSERVABLE */
        createStringObservable().subscribe(createStringSubscriber())
    }


    fun createStringObservable(): Observable<String> {
        val myObservable: Observable<String> = Observable.create {
            subscriber ->
            subscriber.onNext("Hello, World!")
            subscriber.onComplete()
        }

        return myObservable
    }

    fun createStringSubscriber(): Subscriber<String> {
        val mySubscriber = object: Subscriber<String> {
            override fun onNext(s: String) {
                println(s)
            }

            override fun onComplete() {
                println("onComplete")
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                println("onError")
            }

            override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription?) {
                println("onSubscribe")
            }
        }

        return mySubscriber
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: What is "an issue"?  You get an exception or nothing happens?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

pay close attention to the types.

`Observable.subscribe()` has three basic variants:

- one that accepts no arguments
- several that accept an `io.reactivex.functions.Consumer`
- one that accepts an `io.reactivex.Observer`

the type you're attempting to subscribe with in your example is `org.reactivestreams.Subscriber` (defined as part of the Reactive Streams Specification). you can [refer to the docs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#subscriber) to get a fuller accounting of this type, but suffice to say it's not compatible with any of the overloaded `Observable.subscribe()` methods.

here's a modified example of your `createStringSubscriber()` method that will allow your code to compile:

```
fun createStringSubscriber(): Observer<String> {
        val mySubscriber = object: Observer<String> {
            override fun onNext(s: String) {
                println(s)
            }

            override fun onComplete() {
                println("onComplete")
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                println("onError")
            }

            override fun onSubscribe(s: Disposable) {
                println("onSubscribe")
            }
        }

        return mySubscriber
    }
```

the things changed are:

1. this returns an `Observer` type (instead of `Subscriber`)
2. `onSubscribe()` is passed a `Disposable` (instead of `Subscription`)

.. and as mentioned by 'Vincent Mimoun-Prat', lambda syntax can really shorten your code.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Here's an example using pure RxJava 2 (ie not using RxKotlin)
        Observable.create<String> { emitter ->
            emitter.onNext("Hello, World!")
            emitter.onComplete()
        }
                .subscribe(
                        { s -> println(s) },
                        { e -> println(e) },
                        {      println("onComplete") }
                )

        // ...and here's an example using RxKotlin. The named arguments help
        // to give your code a little more clarity
        Observable.create<String> { emitter ->
            emitter.onNext("Hello, World!")
            emitter.onComplete()
        }
                .subscribeBy(
                        onNext     = { s -> println(s) },
                        onError    = { e -> println(e) },
                        onComplete = {      println("onComplete") }
                )
    }
```

i hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, That really helped.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin), that will simplify a lot of things and make code more concise.

```
val list = listOf("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Epsilon")

list.toObservable() // extension function for Iterables
        .filter { it.length >= 5 }
        .subscribeBy(  // named arguments for lambda Subscribers
                onNext = { println(it) },
                onError =  { it.printStackTrace() },
                onComplete = { println("Done!") }
        )
```

Comment: looking at the different ways to create the .subscribe() part. doesn't seem to be a lot of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 2):

```
val observer = object: Observer<Int> {
    override fun onNext(t: Int) {
        // Perform the value of `t`
    }
    override fun onComplete() {
        // Perform something on complete
    }
    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
        // Disposable provided
    }
    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        // Handling error
    }
}
```