# Unable to create Observable in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android

I am trying to create Observable in kotlin .But its giving error unresolved reference on OnSubscribe method

```
  fun getDisposableObserver(): Observable<Background> {

        return Observable.create(object :Observable.OnSubscribe<Background> ->{})
    }
```

I tried this snippet .It also does not work

```
  Observable.create(object : ObservableOn.OnSubscribe<Int> {
            override fun call(subscriber: Subscriber<in Int>) {
                for(i in 1 .. 5)
                    subscriber.onNext(i)

                subscriber.onCompleted()
            }
        })
```

What i am doing wrong ?,How can i create Observable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45766721/3395198

Answer (score 5):

If you want to control the items emission by your self, you can create an `Observable` with `.create` method, like this

```
    Observable.create({ e: ObservableEmitter<String> -> e.onNext("") })

    Observable.create(object: ObservableOnSubscribe<String> {
        override fun subscribe(e: ObservableEmitter<String>) {
            e.onNext("")
        }
    })
```

But in this case you will have to call `onNext`, `onComplete`, `onError` by your own.

But if you want a much simpler solution, you can create it like

```
Observable.just(1)

Observable.fromCallable { 1 }
```

Comment: upvoted, but the preferred style of the first approach is to omit the parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

Simple example with ObservableEmitter

```
    val obs = Observable.create<Int> {
        for(i in 1 .. 5)
            it.onNext(i)

        it.onComplete()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using Architecture Components, but if i want to observe Background i think that MutableLiveData and LiveData could help

```
private val _background = MutableLiveData<Background>()
val background: LiveData<Background> = _background

fun editBackground(newBackground : Background) {
   _background.postValue(newBackground)
}
```

Put this code inside a ViewModel or a Presenter.
Then in your View (Activity/Fragment) you can observe background in this way

```
viewModel.background.observe(this, Observer { newValue ->

        })
```